# During insert : E11000 duplicate key error index

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using mongojs and Node.js to insert a document in mongodb.
It is a REST API and there is only one instance of mongojs (with native drive). Everytime, there is an api call, SAME mongojs object is used to perform mongodb operations. Now, I get the following error when trying to insert a document.

```
{
name: "MongoError"
err: "E11000 duplicate key error index: testdb.userComment.$_id_ dup key: { :    ObjectId('51727190bb4ab52a80024c09') }"
code: 11000
n: 0
connectionId: 225
ok: 1
}
```

The document is always unique
I tried `db.userComment.getIndexs()` and it shows the index is on _id . Can anyone help me how I can fix this problem ?

Comment: `_id` must be unique in MongoDB. If you have a new document, it's easiest if you just don't set the `_id` field and one will be automatically assigned by either the driver or the database. Either way, it will be unique.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether its a right fix, but everytime a document is inserted, I am explicitly creating a new ObjectID instead leaving the fate to mongodb driver. I used the following piece of code

`commentData._id = require('mongodb').BSONPure.ObjectID();`

Comment: Is this an answer to your question, or additional information about your question?

Comment: It's also available here: `var id=require('mongodb').ObjectID()`

Comment: are you creating a new one?  Have you looked at what's being assigned?  Do you need a "new " in front of that?

Comment: @wiredprairie I fixed using the above piece of code. But, I am unable to understand "why mongodb is not creating unique _id in this case"

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Yes, I am creating a new one. I find that _id is cached somewhere and the same is being used when I am inserting a new record.

Comment: hard to know what was wrong in your code since you didn't include any of it in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

This question seems to be a duplicate of this one :
[Getting "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error when inserting into mongo using the Java driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119928/getting-err-e11000-duplicate-key-error-when-inserting-into-mongo-using-the/24541035)

I found an answer [on this page](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/APLpTS4iIuw). I’m guessing your code looks something like this (greatly simplified)?:

```
doc = {} 
for i in xrange(2): 
    doc['i'] = i 
    collection.insert(doc)
```

The problem is that PyMongo injects an _id field into the document, *if the `_id` field does not exist*, before inserting it (`_id` is always generated client side with 10gen drivers). That means that the first time through the loop `_id` is added by the insert method. Since `doc` is defined outside the loop, each subsequent pass through the loop uses the *same* value for `_id`.

Solution:

1. Delete the key _id

> ```
> for i in xrange(2): 
>     doc['i'] = i 
>     if '_id' in doc: 
>         del doc['_id'] 
>     collection.insert(doc)
> ```

2. Or create manually a new one:

> ```
> from bson.objectid import ObjectId 
> for i in xrange(2): 
>     doc['i'] = i 
>     doc['_id'] = ObjectId() 
>     collection.insert(doc)
> ```