# Getting "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error when inserting into mongo using the Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, twitter4j

> Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey: {
>   "serverUsed" : "localhost/127.0.0.1:27017" , "err" : "E11000 duplicate
>   key error index: twitterdb03.LevelAFollowers.$*id*  dup key: { :
>   ObjectId('52d5636de408652b4853a8fe') }" , "code" : 11000 , "n" : 0 ,
>   "connectionId" : 12 , "ok" : 1.0}

I'm using mongo 2.11.1

Never had problems with simple write operations in java

```
myMap.put(inid, followersList);
myObj.putAll(myMap);
myIdMapCollection.insert(myObj);
```

Answer (score 23):

I found an answer [on this page](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/APLpTS4iIuw). I’m guessing your code looks something like this (greatly simplified)?:

```
doc = {} 
for i in xrange(2): 
    doc['i'] = i 
    collection.insert(doc)
```

The problem is that PyMongo injects an _id field into the document, *if the `_id` field does not exist*, before inserting it (`_id` is always generated client side with 10gen drivers). That means that the first time through the loop `_id` is added by the insert method. Since `doc` is defined outside the loop, each subsequent pass through the loop uses the *same* value for `_id`.

Solution:

1. Delete the key _id

> ```
> for i in xrange(2): 
>     doc['i'] = i 
>     if '_id' in doc: 
>         del doc['_id'] 
>     collection.insert(doc)
> ```

2. Or create manually a new one:

> ```
> from bson.objectid import ObjectId 
> for i in xrange(2): 
>     doc['i'] = i 
>     doc['_id'] = ObjectId() 
>     collection.insert(doc)
> ```

Comment: Thanks, finally a useful and simple solution.

Answer (score 7):

Try calling `myIdMapCollection.save(myObj);` instead of `myIdMapCollection.insert(myObj);`

The `save` method, unlike `insert` does upsert, meaning if a document contains `_id`, it replaces that document.

My guess is that you had fetched the `DBObject` using a cursor | query, had manipulated it, and you want to persist the changes. In that case, `save` is the right way to do it.

So, when calling `insert` the `DBObject` is already associated with `_id`, calling `insert` thus fails, because you already have a document with that `_id` in the collection, which should be unique (duplicate index error).

Comment: Finally it works, thanks been held up in this for 2 days

Comment: i have same problem! but with .save it does'nt fix!

Comment: but my duplicate key is in index that i create manually not on _id.is it or this purpose? if yes,how i cat manage that problem?