# MongoDB can not create unique sparse index (duplicate key)

Tags: mongodb

I want to create a unique index over two columns where the index should allow multiple null values for the second part of the index. But:

```
db.model.ensureIndex({userId : 1, name : 1},{unique : true, sparse : true});
```

Throws a duplicate key exception: E11000 duplicate key error index: devmongo.model.$userId_1_name_1  dup key: { : "-1", : null }. I thought because of the sparse=true option the index should allow this constellation? How can I achieve this? I use MongoDB 2.6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compound index should be considered as a whole one, so **unique** requires (userId, name) pair must be unique in the collection, and **sparse** means if both **userId** and **name** missed in a document, it is allowed. The error message shows that there are at least two documents whose (userId, name) pairs are equivalent (if a field missed, the value can be considered as null).

Comment: Hmm ok, so I updated all userId : "-1" to null, but it is still not possible to create the index: E11000 duplicate key error index: devmongo.model.$userId_1_name_1  dup key: { : null, : null }

Comment: @KIC, If you can update the value to null, it means you can remove that field, right? Only remove both fields (userId and name) then **sparse** works which will tell **unique** that the document should be out of constraint of **unique**. So, if you remove all **userId** fields with will -1, make sure **name** fields are not duplicate, because if one field exists, another missed one will be considered as null.

Comment: in fact sparse only works on nonexistant fields. a null field counts as existing field. this is stupid but I have to live with it. Seems that I have to refactor my data model :-(

Answer (score 4):

Sparse compound indexes will create an index entry for a document if ***any*** of the fields exist, setting the value to `null` in the index for any fields that do not exist in the document.  Put another way: a sparse compound index will only skip a document if **all** of the index fields are missing from the document.

As of v3.2, [partial indexes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-partial/#index-type-partial) can be used to accomplish what you're trying to do.  You could use:

```
db.model.ensureIndex({userId : 1, name : 1}, { partialFilterExpression: { name: { $exists: true },  unique: true });
```

which will only index documents that have a `name` field.

**NB:** This index cannot be used by mongo to handle a query by `userId` as it will not contain all of the documents in the collection.  Also, a `null` *in the document* is considered a value and a field that has a `null` value *exists*.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turns out field names are case sensitive.

So creating a compound index on `{field1 : 1, field2 : 1}` is not the same as `{Field1 : 1, Field2 : 1}`