# MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

My database schema is

```
var Account = new Schema({
    email : String,
    name : String ,
   family : String ,
   password : String
   });
```

I want to use email and password for authentication with passport. my code is:

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
passport.use('register', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, email, password, done) {
        Account.findOne({ 'email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
            if (err)
            {
                return done(err);
            }
                else
                {
                var newaccount = new Account();

                newaccount.password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password);
                newaccount.email = req.body.email;
                newaccount.name = req.body.name;
                newaccount.family = req.body.family;

                // save the user
                newaccount.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                    {
                        console.log('Error in Saving user: '+err);
                        throw err;
                    }
               }
        });
```

Although I don't have any username field in

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: Account.accounts.$username_1       dup key: { : null }
```

The first time I can insert in database and I don't have any error but for second time I have this error that I think it assumes username as key and in first time it sets username as null so for second time that it want to try to set username as null throw error because of duplicate key. I search the internet a lot . I drop the database and I use  `db.Account.dropIndexes()` but the problem was not solved.

Comment: This is same question as posted here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430220/e11000-duplicate-key-error-index-in-mongodb-mongoose

Comment: The collection that will be used is `accounts`, not `Account`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E11000 duplicate key error index in mongodb mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430220/e11000-duplicate-key-error-index-in-mongodb-mongoose)

Comment: This is already answered here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430220/e11000-duplicate-key-error-index-in-mongodb-mongoose?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430220/e11000-duplicate-key-error-index-in-mongodb-mongoose?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

The error message is because a record with null as the username is already present. You have a username feild with the null value.Mongo will only permit one indexed feild with the null value.If there is more than one document without a value for the indexed field or is missing the indexed field, the index build will fail with a duplicate key error.You can use sparse index.

Just remove the null document.

Check with mydb.users.getIndexes() You can  manually remove the unwanted index with mydb.users.dropIndex()