# How to fix duplicate key error in mongodb, and comply with createIndexes method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

im getting 'E11000' error while i'm trying to create second record (for TipSchema) in my database. My models looks like this:

```
var TipSchema = new mg.Schema({
    created: String,
    title: String,
    toWin: String,
    stake: String,
    imagecover: String,
    tipcontext: String,
    isFree: String,
    result: String
});

var UserSchema = new mg.Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true, index: true, unique: true},
    password: String,
    mail: String
});
```

> Error: "E11000 duplicate key error index: x.y.$username_1 dup key: { :
>   null }' }"

my indexes looks like this:

INDEXED FIELD(S)    UNIQUE  SPARSE  TTL SIZE
{ "_id": 1 }    (true)  (false) -   7.98 KB 
{ "username": 1 }   true    (false) -   7.98 KB

What should i do to get this going? Few days ago i didn't have this problem, is that caused by "DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead."?

I've dropped entire db, and made everything again, but didn't help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430220/e11000-duplicate-key-error-index-in-mongodb-mongoose

Comment: Should just need to add `sparse: true` to your `username` definition and then drop the index (or collection) so that it can be rebuilt properly.