# connect the mongodb remote server Error : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have following error occurred

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection:
>   LearningLocker_V2.statements index: id_1 dup key: { : null }

My code is

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const xapi = require('vtc-lrs');
app.use("/xapi", new xapi());
let options = {
    lrs: new xapi.LRS(),
    connectionString: "mongodb://192.168.1.38:27017/LearningLocker_V2",
    getUser: function (req, username, password) {
        return new xapi.Account("lrsuser", "test123", true, true);
    },
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:8010/xapi"
};
app.use("/xapi", new xapi(options));
```

In the above code, I connect the mongodb remote server but it's not working. one more thing i use the xapi vts-lrs so don't know how to work with this.

Comment: The error message says that there's already a record with null as the id. In other words, you already have a statements without an id.

Check with LearningLocker_V2.statements.getIndexes() if this is the case and manually remove the unwanted index with LearningLocker_V2.statements.dropIndex(<name>).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E11000 duplicate key error index in mongodb mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430220/e11000-duplicate-key-error-index-in-mongodb-mongoose)

Comment: You can check the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430220/e11000-duplicate-key-error-index-in-mongodb-mongoose. This answer explains in detail and will help you easily to resolve the issue

Comment: @Think-Twice i already use that solution to drop the index still it's not working that's why i am posting as a new question.