# How to fix and prevent duplicate key error in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, c9.io

I've been working on a hobby project recently and I've encountered a problem I can't seem to figure out, even after scouring the internet for an answer. I'm using Node.js on c9.io with MongoDB. Anytime I try to create a new entry into the database, the first entry works and goes through fine, but then the second one causes an error.

E11000 duplicate key error collection: project.tasks index: username_1 dup key: 
{ : null }'

**My Schema:**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    task: String,
    region: String,
    cost: String,
    when: String,
    isAccepted: Boolean,
    author: {
        id:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: "User"
        }
    },
    tasker: {
        id : { 
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "User"
        }
    }
}); 

taskSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Task", taskSchema);
```

**My Post Request:**

```
app.post("/taskers/index/show", function(req, res){
   var task = req.body.task;
   var newTask = {
      task: task.task, 
      region: task.region, 
      cost: task.cost, 
      when: task.when, 
      isAccepted: false, 
      author: req.user._id, 
      tasker: req.user._id
   };
   console.log("STSOTSOTSOTOOPP");
   Task.create(newTask, function(err, newlyCreated){
      if(err){
         console.log(err);
      } else {
         console.log(newlyCreated);
         res.redirect("/users/index");
      }
   });
});
```

If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong or can lead me to a solution, that would be amazing as I've been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: You have a field `username` in tasks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `E11000 duplicate key error collection: project.tasks index: username_1 dup key: { : null }`

This error is coming from mongo (not from mongoose). Removing indexes from your mongoose schema will not have any impact on the underlying collection so you'll now want to remove the unique index on `username` from your `tasks` collection.

This index was likely created by previous code that we no longer see (or perhaps by that `taskSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);` -- that sounds suspiciously like the kind of thing that would want an index on `username`).

If you connect to mongo using the shell, you should be to run `db.tasks.getIndexes()` to see that unique username index, and then use the [`dropIndexCommand`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/) to remove the offending index.

See [E11000 duplicate key error index in mongodb mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430220/e11000-duplicate-key-error-index-in-mongodb-mongoose) for more details about how mongoose & mongo interact.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Reading what you said I realized that I did not need that passport local mongoose as it is not user, and then I dropped the collection and tried again and it works. Cannot thank you enough!!

Comment: Can i use it without remove indexes or are there any way to use uniqueness in database layer without throw error (just ignore abd keep continue!)

Answer (score 0):

Open MongoDB compass and connect same Database that you are using in your code,

1. open your Db and select your collection in MongoDB Compass
2. navigate to indexes section and remove unnecessary index
3. save