# Unknown Directive "unique" - Mongoose and GraphQL

Tags: mongoose, graphql

I am new to graphql and tried to add a unique schema in graphql but got such error.
This is the schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const incidentSchema = new Schema({
  incidentNumber: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  releaseDate: {type: String, required: true}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Incident', incidentSchema);
```

In graphql mutation:

```
addIncident: {
      type: IncidentType,
      args: {
        incidentNumber: { type: GraphQLString },
        releaseDate: { type: GraphQLString }
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        let incident = new Incident({
          incidentNumber: args.incidentNumber,
          releaseDate: args.releaseDate
        });
        return incident.save();
      }
    }
```

Do not know what needs to be done for this issue

Comment: This error seems specific to GraphQL, not mongoose or MongoDB. Where do you see this error? Is it returned as part of the errors array in your GraphQL response? If so, what is the query you're sending?

Comment: If I remove unique constraint from the schema then everything is working fine but I want that field to be unique

Comment: Odd. Where are you seeing the error? Is there a stack trace with it?

Comment: Thanks I have solved the problem there was a @unique in the query. But could you help me this error:

Comment: Message: E11000 duplicate key error collection:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430220/e11000-duplicate-key-error-index-in-mongodb-mongoose

Answer (score 0):

This error message is normally returned when a query is made using a directive that isn't supported by the server. It sounds like your query includes the `@unique` directive, but there is no such directive defined server-side. You can check your API's documentation to see which directives are supported. It's also possible to run an introspection query to obtain that information:

```
query GetDirectives {
  __schema {
    directives {
      name
      description
      locations
      args {
        name
        description
        defaultValue
        type {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```