# How to delete duplicate record from a particular collection in a database in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Schema - 
Database: yelp_camp,
Collection: campgrounds,
Number of records in the collection is equaled to Four

ISSUE - Duplicate records exist in the collection, wish to delete all except the first one.

The database collection snapshot,
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc9729f48ec2b0add99866e"), "name" : "CampAliBaba101234", "image" : "https://photosforclass.com/download/flickr-2770447094", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc974b46e587f0b00855b0d"), "name" : "CampAliBaba101234", "image" : "https://photosforclass.com/download/flickr-2770447094", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc9facd11f218081b57f8f0"), "name" : "CampAliBaba101234", "image" : "https://photosforclass.com/download/flickr-2770447094", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cca658c5ecabc0a7ff79e4e"), "name" : "CampAliBaba101234", "image" : "https://photosforclass.com/download/flickr-2770447094", "__v" : 0 }
Tried using the below-mentioned code but in vain,

Tried below mentioned mongo query in shell,
db.campgrounds.ensureIndex({"name":1}, {unique:"true", dropDups:"true"})

Expected -
The duplicate records should be deleted and only one unique record should exist.

Actual -
The following error is returned,
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: yelp_camp.campgrounds index: image_1 dup key: { : \"https://photosforclass.com/download/flickr-2770447094\" }",
        "code" : 11000,
        "codeName" : "DuplicateKey"
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430220/e11000-duplicate-key-error-index-in-mongodb-mongoose

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this

```
db.getCollection('Test').find({  
   "name":"CampAliBaba101234"
}).forEach((data)=>{  
   var i = 0; 
      db.getCollection('Test').find(   {  
      "name":"CampAliBaba101234"
   }   ).forEach((doc)=>   {  
      if (i>0)   db.getCollection('Test').remove(      {  
         _id:data._id
      }      ) 
        i++
   }   )
});
```

Comment: I am looking for a query that can be used in shell i.e. command line
Could you please help me with the same?

Comment: I just tried this in Robo 3T and worked fine. Let me check. Please try it in shell. If any error ?