# MongoError: E11000 duplicate error key for index. Parameter is showing as null even though i pass in the info

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been looking through reddit and n have tried the solutions in the following links but have not worked.
[E11000 duplicate key error index in mongodb mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430220/e11000-duplicate-key-error-index-in-mongodb-mongoose)

Basically I have a list schema and a user schema and I want to index to have a user and a list name associated with it.
Here is my list schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      maxLength: 50
    },
    description: String,
    createdBy: {
      type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
      ref: 'user',
      required: true
    }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
)

listSchema.index({ user: 1, name: 1 }, { unique: true })

export const List = mongoose.model('list', listSchema)
```

This is my controller (its generic for other schemas but it works for them)

```
export const createOne = model => async (req, res) => {
  console.log('logging user id', req.user._id)
  const createdBy = req.user._id
  try {
    const doc = await model.create({ ...req.body, createdBy: createdBy })
    res.status(201).json({ data: doc })
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
    return res.status(400).end()
  }
}
```

Everytime I pass in the user I get the user as null as an error.

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: api-design.lists index: user_1_name_1 dup key: { user: null, name: "08/29/2020" }
driver: true,
  index: 0,
  code: 11000,
  keyPattern: { user: 1, name: 1 },
  keyValue: { user: null, name: '08/29/2020' }
```

user appears as null even though i passed in their ._id from the other collection

Can anyone help me out please? I have tried dropping the indexes from the collection and dropping all the lists already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you should use this:
`listSchema.index({ createdBy: 1, name: 1 }, { unique: true });`
instead of
`listSchema.index({ user: 1, name: 1 }, { unique: true });`