# E11000 duplicate key, without a duplicate key in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Promise, which I am resolving and then I am iterating through it while saving to a mongo database with mongoose.

I am absolutely sure that I have no duplicates (see output) and I still get the following duplicate key error. It might be related to the promise. The first object gets saved normally, and then it crashes.

```
Promise.resolve(members).then(function(value){
    value.forEach(member => {
        Player.findById(member['id'], function(err, foundPlayer){
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }else{
                if(foundPlayer) console.log(member['id'] + ' already registered.');
                else{
                    console.log('saving with id ' + member['id']);
                    new Player({name: member['nickname'], _id: member['id']}).save();
                } 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**The output is:**

```
saving with id 515595203781066753
saving with id 725997594014384139
saving with id 740967607624269855
(node:29052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: users.players index: id_1 dup key: { id: null }
...
(node:29052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
...
(node:14580) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:14580) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: users.players index: id_1 dup key: { id: null }
...
(node:14580) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

**What I tried:**

- I tried implementing async behaviour, but failed.
- I tried using the default assigned IDs by mongoose instead of mine, but same error

**The model:**

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');

var PlayerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     _id: {type: String},
     name: String,
     points: {type: Number, default: 0}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Player", PlayerSchema);
```

**EDIT**

In the mongo database, this gets saved:

`{"_id":"515595203781066753","points":{"$numberInt":"0"},"name":"somename","__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}`

Comment: Is it possible to show the list of players and their ID's that you're trying to use?

Comment: @MohamedMoselhy How do you mean? The ids are visible in the output. And the member['nickname'] field is a string, it is unique, but shouldn't have to be. (At the moment I'm only trying to save those 3 players).

If you mean the result in the mongodb, I can add it. But it is just the first id with a random name.

Comment: This could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430220/e11000-duplicate-key-error-index-in-mongodb-mongoose

Maybe you're trying to insert two documents (sure, they might have different ID's, but they could be both storing a null no-duplicates field)

Comment: @MohamedMoselhy I read this before I wrote the question and it did not help, because he actually had a duplicate (even if it was empty)

Comment: I wonder why the second object doesn't get saved, even though it doesn't produce an error right away

Comment: @MohamedMoselhy sorry, my fault. The error gets repeated multiple times after the first time. I will change the OP

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222082/discussion-between-mohamed-moselhy-and-hertelukas).

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, there is a unique index on a field named `id`.

```
index: id_1 dup key: { id: null }
```

In the save call, you are setting `_id`, but not `id`:

```
new Player({name: member['nickname'], _id: member['id']}).save();
```

When building index entries, MongoDB represents missing fields with `null`.

The `save()` function returns a promise, so it is quite likely that you have reached the 3rd or 4th document before the first error gets returned.

Comment: I tried that. I changed the mentioned line to this: ```new Player({name: member['nickname'], _id: member['id'], id: member['id']}).save();```

And before saving I print out ```member['id']```, so I am absolutely sure it is unique. I get the exact same error message